# jQuery rebind listeners after ajax success

Tags: jquery, ajax, events, listener, bind

I am trying to add behaviour to DOM objects inserted via AJAX.

From what I read in the [jQuery Api Docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aAJAX_and_Events) I think it would be best to have some scoped `onInit(scope)` handler to perform event binding on the new content.

So far I've got this:

```
function onInit(scope) {
    console.log('init', scope);
    $('.sometestclass', scope).css({'color':'red'});
}

(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('click', '.ajax-button', function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            $target = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                url: 'validUrl',
                ...
                success: function(data) {
                    var $new = $target.replaceWith(data);    
                    onInit($new);
                },
            }); 
        });

    onInit(this);
});

})(jQuery);
```

Via firebug I can verify the ajax call is succesfull, the contents gets replaced as desired. `onInit` gets called in the document.ready event and after the ajax.sucess event. There are no errors shown in the firebug console.
Yet there is no reaction to the second onInit($scope) call.

What am I doing wrong here?

The jquery version used is 1.9.1.

Comment: What is $new exactly?  And what do you expect $new to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In replaceWith() doc, you can read:

> Replace each element in the set of matched elements with the provided
>   new content and **return the set of elements that was removed**.

So here, you are calling `init()` function on removed element.

Comment: That's it. exactly. After about an hour of investigating you just tell me I have misread the docs. And you are right. Thank you.